# How to remap keys so that failed commands don't stop the command?

Tags: key-bindings

I have the following command in vim to scroll another window when only two windows are open. The specifics are not important as this is a general question, but the example is illustrative.

```
nnoremap <leader>d <C-w>w<C-d><C-w>w
```

This works fine most of the time, but if the other window is already at the bottom then I find my cursor often ends up stuck in the other window. I'm guessing this is because the `<C-d>` fails and the command stops running.

I've come across the same problem in other remappings and I'm sure there is a simple way to code around it. I know that for example in search and replace you stick an `e` at the end. For example:

```
bufdo s/foo/bar/ge | update
```

This allows later commands to run even if no patterns match.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have 2 windows, in both of them you are in the middle of a buffer, and you type the following Ex command:

```
:exe "norm! \<C-W>w\<C-D>\<C-W>w"
```

It should do what your mapping is trying to perform, which is scrolling the other window downwards and give the focus back to the original window.

But if in the other window, your cursor is already at the very bottom of the buffer, it will not give the focus back because, like you said, the `<C-D>` will fail and therefore the last keystrokes, `<C-W>w`, won't be hit by `:normal`.

A possible solution is to break the `:normal` command into 2 parts, where an error may occur.
Here, the error may occur on `<C-D>`, so you could type the following Ex command:

```
:exe "norm! \<C-W>w\<C-D>" | exe "norm! \<C-W>w"
```

Now, even if the first `:normal` command fails at the end, the second `:normal` will still be executed regardless.

---

To convert the previous command into a mapping, you could write this in your `vimrc`:

```
nnoremap <silent> <leader>d :<C-U>exe "norm! \<lt>C-W>w\<lt>C-D>" <bar> exe "norm! \<lt>C-W>w"<CR>
```

---

A few things that may help you better understand the previous mapping:

- In the `{rhs}` of the mapping, `<C-U>` is there just in case you hit a number (by accident) before `<leader>d`.
  If you hit a number before an Ex command, it's automatically converted into a range on the command line. For example, if you hit `5:`, you should see `:.,.+4`.
  But `:execute` doesn't accept a range, so it would raise an error.
  With `<C-U>`, if a range is inserted by accident, it will be deleted.
- `:normal` doesn't need `:execute` to type normal commands, however, `:execute` allows you to prevent `:normal` from typing the whole command line including the pipe.
  That's because `:normal` interprets `|` as a part of its argument, while `:execute` interprets it as a command termination.
  Besides, it allows you to wrap the whole `:normal` command inside a string where control characters may be represented with printable characters (a special type of notation described in `:help expr-quote`). For example, here it allows you to represent a literal `<C-D>` with the notation `\<C-D>`.
- The bang after the `:normal` command is here to prevent the keystrokes that you pass as an argument to be remapped. From `:help :normal`:

  ```
  Without it, when this command is called from a
  non-remappable mapping (:noremap), the argument can
  be mapped anyway.
  ```

  Usually you don't want the keys to be remapped, so even if it should not  be necessary here, it can be a good habit to put a bang after `:norm`. But if for some reason you wanted the keys to be remapped, you could remove the bang.
- When the string executed by `:execute` contains special keys such as `<C-D>` or `<C-W>`, you should use double quotes instead of single ones, otherwise they won't be translated into literal control characters. As a result, instead of typing a literal `<C-D>`, `:normal` would type 5 keys `<`, `C`, `-`, `D` and `>`.
- In a mapping, the notation `<bar>` can be used to represent a pipe character. Another possibility is `\|`, but not `|`. A simple pipe would be interpreted by `:nnoremap` as a command termination instead of a usual character to type.
- The keycode `<lt>` is necessary for the mapping to work. Without it, Vim will automatically translate `<C-W>` and `<C-D>` into literal control characters when your `vimrc` is sourced and the mappings table is filled with all your mapping commands (the one you see through Vim's internal pager when you type `:map`).

---

To better understand why `<lt>` is necessary, suppose you want to define a mapping in command line mode which maps `cw` to the five characters `<C-W>`, and you write this in your vimrc:

```
cnoremap cw <C-W>
```

Now, on the command line, you type (without hitting `Enter` at the end):

```
:exe "norm! \
```

Then, you hit `cw` thinking that it will insert `<C-W>` on the command line.
But instead of getting `:exe "norm! \<C-W>`, you will get `:exe "norm!`. Why?

Because, when your `:cnoremap` command was sourced, inside the mappings table, `<C-W>` was automatically translated into a literal control character.

What's the effect of a literal `<C-W>` on the command line? It deletes the previous word.
Here the previous word was the backslash, so it was deleted. But that's not what you wanted.
You wanted the five characters `<C-W>` to be typed without any translation.
So a better mapping would be:

```
cnoremap cw <lt>C-W>
```

This time, it will work as expected, because when the command will be sourced, inside the mappings table, only `<lt>` will be translated (into the character `<`) and the result will be the 5 desired characters `<` + `C-W>` = `<C-W>`.

You can see `<lt>` as a way to protect a special key from being automatically translated when it's inside the `{rhs}` of a mapping.

Comment: Fantastic answer, extremely thorough and I understand now. Thank you.

Comment: Awesome! Made use of this answer in another context: changed this `noremap my w?\%^\\|# ----------<CR>v/\%$\\|# ----------<CR>$:SlimeSend<CR>'>:noh<CR>
` to this `nnoremap my :exe "norm! w"<CR>?\%^\\|# ----------<CR>v/\%$\\|# ----------<CR>$:SlimeSend<CR>'>:noh<CR>` because the initial `w` fails if the cursor is at the end of the file.

Comment: I realized that the problematic part of the mapping can be run separately using `:exe` as you explain, but I can keep the other part in the default mapping format by inserting a <CR> after the Exe step.